# rails 5 select filepath to download CSV-file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In one of my models I got a function to write CSV in a new file:

```
def self.all_to_csv(path)
 columns = %w[number name description]
 CSV.open(path, 'wb') do |csv|
  csv << columns.map
  in_year.each do |course|
    csv << course.attributes.values_at('number', 'name', 'description')
  end
 end
end
```

It works great.
Now I Would like to create a HTML form to select/create a new file path.
I tried to use the standard html `<input type="file">` but it seems to be for uploading files only, not to download to a specific file path! 
I won't like the user to write a full path by himself because it would be too prone to errors.

Is there a way to select a new path with a file selector (see image) and send it to the server? (no javascript if possible, only html and ruby)

If I use `<input type="file">` this window opens, where I am not able to type in a new file path! I am able to create a file and select it afterwards, but that is not the best solution..

[image: File Selector]

Comment: The browser or server has no access to actually create files in a specific location on the client-machine. A user can download the file, but only the user can specify where to save it. Unless you want to create a folder/location on the server?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method you can access the `params[:file]` and that is a `UploadedFile` instance with the instance method `#path`. Read more in the API http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html#method-i-path

```
uploaded_file = params[:file]
new_filename = uploaded_io.original_filename
unless params[:new_filename].blank?
  new_filename = params[:new_filename]
end

File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', new_filename), 'wb') do |file|
  file.write(uploaded_file.read)
end
```

Comment: But how do I select this file?

Comment: In the browser? Just a regular form and file input. The guide has a section you might want to read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't get it :/ I am using Linux Mint... maybe you got another kind of file selector (added an image to the post)? If not pls give me an example how to enter new file path or how to select a directory and add a filename afterwards.

Comment: Da könnt ma eigentlich auch auf Deutsch reden...

No, you can change the name of the file you upload magically, you have to add a text input for this and use that param in your controller. some apps actually do have that pattern. The guide has an example for moving the file around and I updated my answer a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to download a csv file by the browser to the computer.
I thought `csv.open()` is the function for downloading files from the server to the client. @nathanvda was totally right when he said "server has no access to actually create files in a specific location on the client-machine". So my final solution looks like this:

Instead of using `csv.open()` which directly writes to a file, I use `CSV.generate` to create a String and pass it to the controller.

*course.rb*

```
def self.all_to_csv
  columns = %w[Nummer Name Beschreibung Max.Teilnehmer]
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << columns.map
    in_year.each do |course|
      csv << course.attributes.values_at('number', 'name', 'description', 'max_visitor')
    end
  end
end
```

In the controller I receive a filename from a simple html form and display the response as a csv file (`type: 'text/csv`) attachment in a download dialog (`disposition: 'attachment'`).
[send_data documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data)

*courses_controller.rb'

```
def download_courses_csv
  filename = params[:filename]
  send_data Course.all_to_csv, filename: "#{filename}.csv", type: 'text/csv', disposition: 'attachment'
end
```

Et Voila!

[image: download dialog]